# How to assign -INFINITY amongst others to multiple variables?

Tags: matlab, pseudocode

I have this line of pseudocode that I am trying to translate in Matlab:

```
(maxSum, maxStartIndex, maxEndIndex) := (-INFINITY, 0, 0)
```

I have translated the second and third variables simply assigning a 0:

```
maxStartIndex=0;
maxEndIndex=0;
```

How should I translate this line?

```
maxSum= -INFINITY
```

I have not find reference for this.

Comment: `-inf` is not what you want? or basically `[maxSum, maxStartIndex, maxEndIndex] = deal(-inf,0,0)`

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks a lot. I had no reference for it. Please post it as answer I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you're just looking for [**`deal`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html?refresh=true):

```
[maxSum, maxStartIndex, maxEndIndex] = deal(-inf,0,0)
```